# r- function over columns with if statement

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I need to do a function over columns to fill another column that represents if the numbers in the row grow or  (mantain or decrease). I'm doing it considering 4 values:

```
df<-data.frame(a=c('cli1','cli2','cli3'),b=c(3,8,6), c=c(2,6,7), d=5:7, e=c(1,5,10), f=1:3)
```

The function would be:

```
f2<-function (tbl) {x<-data.frame(cid=tbl[,1])
                    for (i in 5:(ncol(tbl)) ) {                                            
if  
  ((tbl[,i]+tbl[,i-1])/(tbl[,i-2]+tbl[,i-3])-1 >0)
    {Y='sube'}

else if 
  ((tbl[,i]+tbl[,i-1])/(tbl[,i-2]+tbl[,i-3])-1<=0)  
    {Y='baja'}

x[,paste('_Disc',colnames(tbl)[i],sep='')]<-Y
}

return (x)}
```

When I apply it, I get:

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In if ((tbl[, i] + tbl[, i - 1])/(tbl[, i - 2] + tbl[, i - 3]) >  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

How can I use the if to go row by row iwthout using another for? Thanks.

Comment: You are violating many syntax rules. Start with something small, test, and slowly build from there. Try to indent your code like people recommend to make it more readable (and you'll find you have unbalanced `{}`). Also, `and` and `then` are not part of R's syntax.

Comment: @flodel thanks I changed it, and now compiles, But still get an error. I think might be the case that the if can't handle columns arrays an evaluate them row by row. How can I solve it easily and not having to introduce another for?

Comment: @Gaby P you have multiple values, and some of them are NAs.  I don't know how you want to evaluate it.  For example, in the first case: `indx1 <- (df[,5]+df[,4])/(df[,3]+df[,2]);  all(na.omit(indx1) >0)#[1] TRUE` Is it something like the one I showed? In that case, you could use `if(all(na.omit(indx1)>0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   f2New <- function(tbl) {
     x <- data.frame(cid = tbl[, 1])
     for (i in 5:(ncol(tbl))) {
     indx <- (tbl[, i] + tbl[, i - 1])/(tbl[, i - 2] + tbl[, i - 3])
     Y <- ifelse(indx > 0, "sube", ifelse(indx2 <= 0, "baja", NA))
     x[, paste("_Disc", colnames(tbl)[i], sep = "")] <- Y
     }
    return(x)
   }

  f2New(df)
  #   cid _Disce _Discf
  #1 cli1   <NA>   sube
  #2 cli2   sube   sube
  #3 cli3   sube   sube
```

Comment: @Gaby P Glad to know that it worked.  I was confused as you mentioned about growing/maintain/decrease in the post.